# How to USE a stored procedure's result inside an "insert into" statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am using MySQLWorkbench v8.0.22 on macOS bigSur 11.4.

I have a stored procedure which gets account name (office rent/electricity bill/cash in hand etc) , description, debit, credit, type of account (asset/liability/expense etc), and output in its parameters.

Here, I want to insert fields into "transaction" table, and some fields in "account_transaction" table.

Now, problem is that how can i store the *integer variable* 'account_id', and then insert it into "account_transaction" table at line 3.

This is my stored procedure:

```
-- drop procedure AddTransaction
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddTransaction` (in `acc` varchar(255), in `desc` varchar(1023), in `dr` int, in `cr` int, in `atype` varchar(16), out `output` int) -- it would be called after checking: total debit = total credit
BEGIN
    declare toaid int default -1;
    -- set @toaid =-1;
    set @toa=concat('select `account_id` into `', toaid, '` from `', atype, '` where `name`="', acc, '"');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @toa;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    
    insert into `transaction` (`date`, `account`, `description`, `debit`, `credit`)
        select now(), `acc`, `desc`, `dr`, `cr`; -- line 1
    insert into `account_transaction` values( -- line 2
        (select @toaid), -- line 3
        (select `transaction`.`id` from `transaction` where `transaction`.`id` = (select max(`transaction`.`id`) from `transaction`))); -- line 4
    set `output`=1; -- success
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This is how i am calling it:

```
CALL AddTransaction ('cash in hand', 'c i h', 4000, 0, "asset", @output);
select 'Returned value:' , @output;
```

The error:

```
Error Code: 1327. Undeclared variable: -1
```

This is account table:

```
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  foreign key (`user_id`) references `user`(`id`)
)
```

This is transaction table:

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `account` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(1023) DEFAULT NULL,
  `debit` int NOT NULL,
  `credit` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

This is account_trasnaction table:

```
CREATE TABLE `account_transaction` (
  `account_id` int NOT NULL,
  `transaction_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`account_id`, `transaction_id`),
  foreign key (`account_id`) references `account`(`id`),
  foreign key (`transaction_id`) references `transaction`(`id`)
)
```

Comment: You already store the account id in a session variable, so not sure what you need help with!

Comment: you try to insert varchar in int field into transaction table : select now(), `acc`, `desc`, `dr`, `cr`;

Comment: @bigtheo no i don't. Please clear what you are saying!

Comment: look at this :  insert into `transaction` (`date`, `account`, `description`, `debit`, `credit`)
        select now(), `acc`, `desc`, `dr`, `cr`; -- line 1

Comment: @bigtheo i still don't get what's the issue in line 1. All datatypes are correspondingly same.

Comment: No, I'm talking about @output.

Comment: Check the content of `@toa`: `select \`account_id\` into \`-1\` from \`asset\` where \`name\`="cash in hand"`. Try `set @toa = concat('select \`account_id\` into @toaid from \`', atype, '\` where \`name\`="', acc, '"');`.